# Laravel 8 with Jetstream no style and js appeared

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-jetstream

I just installed jetstream on a laravel 8 empty, when i try to connect myself on the login page, the style and the js doesnt appear.

I tried to delete the vendor folder and do the composer install command and nothing changed.

If you want to see : https://curationprojet.roberts.etu.mmi-unistra.fr/caracara/public/login

The welcome page is normal, just jetstream pages are bugged.

Comment: If you check the `network` tab in your browser developer console, it can't locate your `app.css` file. Have you compiled your assets and configured your build workflow correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you already ran all the commands for the installation you should use:

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Comment: yes i did it on the folder of the project